# my prime number function keeps a returning a TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

so I'm writing an is_prime function, and it keeps returning a TypeError when I set the argument to a float. the function returns Returns True if num is prime. A number X is prime if it is only divisible by 1 and by X. You can consider that numbers 0 and 1 are prime and it Returns False if num is not prime. Also, If the argument is not an integer or num < 0, the function should return None.

so for examples:

- For input argument "hello!", it should return None, because the input argument is a string
- For input argument "23", it should return None, because the input argument is a string
- For input argument 12.34, it should return None, because the input argument is a float.
- For input argument 1, it should return True
- For input argument 4, it should return False (number 4 is divisible by 2)

so here is my code, I really don't know what the problem, any help or criticism would be greatly appreciated...:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num is type(num) and type(str) and num < 0:
        return None
    for i in range(1, num):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: Just a tip: you only need to check up to the square root of the number in your for loop! `for i in range(1, math.floor(num**0.5)):`. You need to `import math` for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I believe this is the algorithm you're going for:

1. check for num being an integer (should also check for it being positive)
2. check each number between 1 & num to see if it divides num
3. if no number divides num then and only then return true.

with all that, the function becomes:

```
def is_prime(num):
    # returns false if num is not an integer
    if not isinstance(num, int):
        return None
    # returns false is divisible by any number 
    # between 1 and num return False
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    # if none of the numbers divide num return True
    return True.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for validation of the variable type is incorrect. To check the type you should use for example

```
if not isinstance(num, int):
    return None
else:
    # check for prime
```

Comment: it still returns a TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float. on the line "for i in range (1, num):"

Comment: You should only allow ints through your function, everything else should return None. See my edit.

Comment: still returns the same float problem "it still returns a "TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float. on the line "for i in range (1, num):